# In Vi, navigate / jump to the brackets around the current block

Tags: navigation, vi, brackets, braces

Supposing we have some code:

```
var f = function(a) {
  var g = {"b" : "c",
           "m" : "n" // cursor is here
           "d" : "e",
           "h" : {
             "i" : "j",
             "k": "l"
             },
           "m" : {
             "n" : {"o":"p"}
             }
           } // want to get to here
}
```

What would be the most economic command in vi to navigate / jump to the closing bracket for the current scope.

Bear in mind:

- we can't use % because we're not already on the opening brace.
- we can't use [{ beacause it's not unmatched
- we could use /{ and n, but this is cumbersome and requires more thinking than should be necessary.

Comment: I'm using the fwd example because it's harder in the snippet given, but moving backward to the opening braces would also be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?{ <ENTER>
 %`

The first line of commands to go to the last opened {

Then `%` to find the matching brace

Answer (score 1):

In Vim, you can use `ya{` which copies the text inside the nearest `{}` to the clipboard, but also moves the cursor to the opening `{`. You can then use `%` to jump to the corresponding ending brace.

Comment: this is good, thanks, but without a side effect would be optimal.